# Connecting Excel and Smartsheet so excel can pull the files from a workspace of Smartsheet

Tags: excel, smartsheet-api, excelquery

I am trying to determine if upgrading Smartsheet to the business tier is worth it right now. The main thing deciding this is whether I can connect all of the files from a workspace to Excel Power Query using the Live Data Connector.

I have searched through the smartsheet help and odbc connector setup page yet I am still not sure if the connector can do this.

What I am trying to do overall is scan many gantt chart files into an excel query and customize the data so each file is turned into a horizontal row of data to be displayed.

I have this working with downloaded smartsheets (now excel files) in a local folder but I want to make sure this works before I get the company to upgrade to the next tier.

Comment: This isn't really the right place for your question (it will likely be closed; a better place is probably https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com ). **For other's reference**: Smartsheet is an SaaS app with spreadsheet-like UI for collaboration/work management, used to assign tasks, track project progress, manage calendars, share, etc.

Comment: I am more specifically asking about the functionality of the connector, would the belong is Software Recommendations?

Comment: The Smartsheet Live Data Connector can look at multiple sheets and can be used with Excel Power Query. Once the data is pulled into your Excel file from Smartsheet you should be able to work as you need with the data. For more assistance on this I would suggest reaching out to Smartsheet Support: https://www.smartsheet.com/gethelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Smartsheet Live Data Connector is an ODBC driver that can be used to pull data from a sheet or report in Smartsheet to any client that supports pulling data from an ODBC Driver. There are [specific instructions for using the Smartsheet Live Data Connector in Excel](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/odbc-docs/#excel---data-connection-wizard) and more [general information about the Live Data Connector](https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/2476166-smartsheet-live-data-connector-connect-smartsheet-and-third-party-tools-via-ODBC) as well.

You might also want to describe the end result you're seeking to a Customer Success Representative at Smartsheet. As the idea of getting each project summarized and then to appear as a single row in a Smartsheet Dashboard or Report is also a capability built into Smartsheet that may meet your needs without having to resort to storing data offline and in multiple places.